# Java missing javax.servlet.httpservlet

Tags: java, maven

When i made new Maven project in Eclipse, using webapp archetype and imported all jars according to pom.xml file, i got red cross on all my .jsp files, saying "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path.

I have added javax.servlet dependency and it didn't help at all.

Any ideas on how to fix it? Can it be caused because of Eclipse since any of my previous maven projects can't be oppened?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringHiberSql</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringHiberSql</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
<org.springframework.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>        
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate resources -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.184428</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.183949</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>


 <build>
 <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
 <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: First test:  Does it compile from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i got red cross on all my .jsp files, saying "The superclass
>   "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path.

Your Maven pom seems ok about this dependency.
The problem comes very probably from Eclipse.
If packaging your application with `mvn clean package` is successful, you know the culprit : Eclipse.
Ideally, this maven command should be used without any IDE wrapper, so from the command line.
 This prevents any side effect from IDE.

Comment: I used mvn clean package and it was succesfull, if problem comes from Eclipse, what should i do? Reinstall it?

Comment: Maybe but not necessarily. As workaround, you can try to add this library in the  libraries of the Eclipse project. It has no incidence on the Maven build. It is just to make Eclipse "happy"

Comment: I updated project, built it again and it partially fixed my problem. Now i don't have missing javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, but i have red cross on my project icon and on java resources. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: What is the error Eclipse is reporting? You can see it in the "problems" tab